# Removing numbers and brackets at end of line and fill placeholder at begining of line

Tags: php, regex

1) How can I remove all numbers, brackets and 's. string' behind the words?

2) If there is a placeholder `--` at the begning of the line, the complete keyword should be generated (if the main keyword has pagenumbers it will be added as a keyword itself; if there is no pagenumber behind that, just the following parts are relevant [i.e. Word1 and Word2])

3) It can be possible that a long keyword has a linebreak. This linebreak should be removed (i.e. last line in the example)

```
Keyword 533 --534
Word1 519, 522
-- any 123
-- another 45, 33
Word2
-- any 23
-- another 5, 3
Key-word 832-- 833,
Keyword, with comma 48, 50 -- 51, 527
Keyword (anything)
Keyword s. remove that
Keyword with
linebreak 12, 344
```

The result should be

```
Keyword
Word1
any Word1
another Word1
any Word2
another Word2
Key-word
Keyword, with comma
Keyword
Keyword
Keyword with linebreak
```

My attempt:

```
$myfile = fopen("file.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
while(!feof($myfile)) {

    $re = "/\\d+(\\s*,\\s*\\d+)*|\\bs\\..*$/im";
    $str = fgets($myfile);
    $subst = "";
    $result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
    if (trim($result)) echo trim($result) . "<br>";
}
fclose($myfile);
```

This works for numbers, commas and the `s.`-string. But I don't know how to do the thing with the `--`placeholder and the linebreaks.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
$myfile = fopen("file.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
while(!feof($myfile)) {
     $re = "/\\d+(\\s*,\\s*\\d+)*|\\bs\\..*$|[-,]+|\\(.*\\)/im";
     $str = fgets($myfile);
     $subst = "";

     $result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
     if (trim($result)) echo trim($result) . "<br>";
}
fclose($myfile);
```

[live demo](http://regex101.com/r/cN8oH7/1)

Comment: What do I have to do with 2) and 3)? Please have a look at the example Word1 and Word2. In your live demo you see the linebreak (which shouldn't be) at the last line. And the placeholders aren't used...